# How can I apply this curl code in guzzle?

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

How can I apply this curl in guzzle? can anybody help me?

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' --user TU_CLIENT_ID:TU_SECRET_ID https://xubio.com/API/1.1/TokenEndpoint
```

Comment: Hey Francisco! Welcome to SO! Have you taken [a stroll through this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question? If you can update your question to show _what you've tried_ , it will be easier for others to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('POST', 'https://xubio.com/API/1.1/TokenEndpoint', [
    'auth' => [env('TU_CLIENT_ID'), env('TU_SECRET_ID')],
'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials']
    ]
]);

return $res->getBody();
```

Hope this helps